How to remove hover for all products in all pages？
I want to remove hover for all products in all pages, how can I do that?

Thanks

Hey, there is not a single file that you can change, and remove  the hover for the category page, and product page you need to enable template path hint and go to that file and remove 'href' from 'a' tab. Thank You!

i found an  answer from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359014/how-do-i-remove-hover-on-product-on-home-and-category-page , but i don't know inset the codes to which file.

You can insert the code on app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
